# What's the recommended way to use SQL Server in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, .net-4.5

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET (Razor, .NET Framework 4.5), and now am attempting to figure out how to use SQL Server in ASP.NET (I'm used to MySQL in PHP, but from what I've seen SQL Server is more popular/works better in ASP.NET). Looking around, there seem to be a lot of ways to do this, some of the ways I've seen include:

- ADO.NET
- OleDb
- LINQ to SQL

LINQ to SQL would be my favorite choice, since I personally love using LINQ in C#, but the documentation I came across looks like it's for .NET Framework 3.5 (though it may just be outdated documentation, or I could be reading it wrong), and I'm not so sure about having an extra layer/bottleneck for speed considerations. What's the most-used way to do this, and where is the best documentation?

Comment: I believe you could be reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) wrong. It is a component of 3.5, but is included in 4.5.

Comment: ^ that's what I assumed, but the fact that it mentioned 3.5 instead of 4.5 makes it feel like a soon-to-be-discontinued feature, or why else do they mention 3.5 in documentation for 4.5?

Comment: Yes, as has been answered and can be seen @peterm's link Entity is the preferred solution for new applications according to Microsoft.

Comment: The "best" way is subjective. EF is MS's ORM, so it is a good thing, assuming you need an ORM. There are lots of "ORM-lite"s to choose form too: Dapper, Massive, Simple.Data, PetaPoco, or roll you own. Really, it depends on what _you need_ - there is no single "best" or even "recommended" way. About the only thing that is a **for sure** thing to follow is to use parameters when passing values to SQL queries - no string concatenation! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally the best choice would be  [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

Comment: that looks great at first glance, reminds me of Windows Azure Mobile Services :)

Comment: theres also NHibernate. I odn;t kow how it is in the international market but its definitly more popular in israel.

Comment: Yes. And if not - there is no sense in using OleDb. THAT would be backward as .NET has native support (SqlClient classes) for the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL has basically been abandoned.  For a better version, use Entity Framework.

see http://www.redmond-recap.com/2012/08/27/entity-framework-a-sorry-history-new-release-5-0-and-future-openness/